# Redirecting Conditionally using React Router

Tags: react-router

I want to go to the page with the link after checking the terms.But nothing happens.

App.tsx

```
   import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Components/Login";
import "./styles/index.scss";

import { Suspense } from "react";
import ToDoScreen from "./Pages/ToDoScreen";
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Suspense fallback={<h2>Loading...</h2>}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/home" component={ToDoScreen} />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.tsx

When the button I want is clicked, it first checks and then redirects to the page.

```
<button onClick={onClick}>Login</button>
```

OnClick :

```
 const onClick = () => {
    if (inputs.name.length < 3 || inputs.lastname.length < 3) {
      alert("name/lastname must be at least 3 characters");
    } else {
      <Link to="/home"></Link>;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link components are supposed to be rendered and not returned or used within event handlers. To dynamically update the route, you should use `history.push` instead

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
function MyComp() {
   const history = useHistory();
   const onClick = () => {
    if (inputs.name.length < 3 || inputs.lastname.length < 3) {
      alert("name/lastname must be at least 3 characters");
    } else {
      history.push("/home");
    }
  };
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Link>` just generates an anchor tag wrapped with some "react-router" functionality.
It won't actually make the user go to a particular route unless, the user clicks on the generated `<a>`.

Instead, you want to use `<Redirect>`. With this, you can redirect the user to a new Route.

Thereby, making your else condition to be

```js
else {
      <Redirect to="/home" />
    }
```

Refer to [the official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) for more information.